# A question on convergence rates of Fourier series and strict convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, soft-question, fourier-analysis

Consider BV functions on a torus. The Fourier partial sum using the first $n$ coefficients will converge to the function at every point of continuity, as $n\to\infty$. The convergence rate is $O(1/n)$. However, the total variation of the partial sum does not converge and grows unbounded as $n \to \infty$. The Cesaro partial sum does not have this problem, and its total variation converges to that of the function as $n\to\infty$. However, the convergence rate of the Cesaro sum, to the actual function (at points of continuity), is $O(\log(n)/n)$ which is slower compared to $O(1/n)$ which is the case for the Fourier partial sum.

I am trying to think of a method to construct the function using the first $n$ coefficients so that it does not have the above-mentioned drawbacks. Meaning, it converges to the function at points of continuity, at a rate $O(1/n)$, and its total variation also converges to that of the function.

Question: What would be the possible applications/usefulness of such a method to other areas of mathematics?

Comment: Your "torus" is a circle? Otherwise what do you mean by "left" and "right" limits?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I have made a significant edit to the problem, now the concept of left and right limits does not exist as I consider convergence at points of continuity only. Now the torus can be of any dimensions.

Comment: This won't answer your question, but if you consider a wavelet series (rather than the Fourier series) of BV functions, then you may find the paper http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/RMI/345 useful. In a nutshell, the space BV is squeezed in between two Besov spaces $B^1_{1,1}\subset BV\subset B^1_{1,\infty}$, and there is a well-developed theory for nonlinear $n$-term approximation of wavelet series for Besov spaces.